# How to close bootstrapper process?

Tags: c#, prism

I initialize the Bootstrapper at the application startup like this:

```
public void StartUp(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    Bootstrapper bs = new BootStrapper();
    bs.Run();
}
```

Is it possible to later stop the bootstrapper process once started and start it again, without closing the main application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot stop the bootstrapping process and then start it again.  I cannot think of a single reason why you would want to do that, and if you are thinking about that then you should re-evaluate your app design.

Comment: Ok, inside the Bootstrapper class I initialize the module, and in this module's Initilaize() method, I instantiate all model objects and register all the views for navigation. However, I have a restart button in my app which should take the user to the initial state of the app at any point. So on this button click I wanted to create new instance of the bootstrapper class again and call Run() method again, but it says that the instance is already running.

Comment: Why? The registrations of your objects does not represent the state of your app. You do not want to re-run the bootstrapper process. Don't even try it. When they click the reset button, just navigate the initial screen into view and reset the state of the app.

Comment: Ok, yes, that's what I already did, and also in addition to that I have to re-instantiate all model objects, which is fine. However, how would I re-instantiate the view-models? They are wired to the views with the locator, and I would like to have brand new view-model objects after clicking restart. Is this possible with prisms view-model locator?

Comment: You are thinking about this all wrong.  You don't reset any object by creating a new instance. You reset the state within the object.  Don't make it harder than it has to be.  When you reset, send a message that all your objects subscribe to, and then they can rest the state of their properties.